# How can I inspect the default copy/move constructors/assignment operators?

Tags: c++, c++17

How do I find out what exactly my classes' default constructors, destructors, and copy/move constructors/assignment operators do?

I know about the rule of 0/3/5, and am wondering what the compiler is doing for me.

If it matters, I'm interested in >=C++17.

Comment: _"How do I find?"_ Check the documentation. For example, for [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), cppreference says: _"...For non-union class types (`class` and `struct`), the constructor performs full member-wise copy of the object's bases and non-static members, in their initialization order, using direct initialization..."_ Link to the standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#14.sentence-1.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks! I'm still learning how to read the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [implicitly-defined copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-defined_copy_constructor)

> ... performs full member-wise copy of the object's bases and non-static members, in their initialization order, using [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization)...

For a simple structure:

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    std::string y;
    double z;
};
```

The copy-constructor would be equivalent to:

```
A::A(A const& otherA)
    : x(otherA.x), y(otherA.y), z(otherA.z)
{
}
```

Comment: Ta a lot! So by my reading, the destructor would be `A::~A(){}`

Comment: @masher Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 3):

It just calls the respective operation for every member and direct base class, nothing else.

E.g. the implicitly generated copy assignment calls copy assignment for every member.

Note that:

- `virtual` bases are always initialized by the most-derived class. Any initializers for the virtual bases in the member-init-lists of any bases are ignored. Example:

  ```
  struct A
  {
      int x;
      A(int x) : x(x) {}
  };

  struct B : virtual A
  {
      B()
          : A(1) // This is ignored when constructing C.
      {}
  };

  struct C : B
  {
      C()
          : A(2) // If A is not default-constructible, removing this causes an error.
      {}
  };

  C c; // .x == 2
  ```
- The implicitly generated default constructor has a unique property (shared by a default constructor that's explicitly `=default`ed in the class body): if the object was created using empty parentheses/braces, any field that would otherwise be uninitialized is zeroed. Example:

  ```
  struct A
  {
      int x;
      // A() = default; // Has the same effect.
  };

  A f; // Uninitialized.
  A g{}; // Zeroed.
  A h = A{}; // Zeroed.
  A i = A(); // Zeroed.
  ```

  This applies to [scalar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_scalar) types, and the effect propagates recursively through member class instances that have the same kind of default constructors.